# SSRS Expression statement for Shoretel abandoned calls <=10 seconds

Tags: reporting-services, expression

I am trying to create a Variable in SSRS Report builder. I have had no success with the expression i created. I am hoping you can assist.

I am trying to exclude abandoned calls <= 10 seconds. The below expression does not seem to be working for me. What am i doing wrong. Any help would be great.

Example: I am looking to achieve a text value "like"  **8** abandoned calls.

```
=(Cdbl(IIF((Fields!ExitReason.Value = 7), IIF ((Fields!ExitReason.Value = 7), (Fields!DurationSeconds.Value) <= 10, (0)), 0))
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to do a conditional count, try something like the following:

```
=Cdbl(Count(IIf(Fields!ExitReason.Value=7, IIf(Fields!DurationSeconds.Value>10, 1, Nothing), Nothing)))
```

In plain English, that expression will count only the rows where seconds <=10 and ExitReason = 7.